# Retrieve the content on file form attachment downloaded from gmail as it is storing in gmail server

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have to retrieve the filename of the content from gmail app.

i get content uri some thing similar to

content://gmail-ls/messages/gaddam40gmail.com/4/attachments/0.1/BEST/false

i am writing this uri but it is going to error ,What i need to do

```
  window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
  if(url.startsWith('content://')) {
    // url is the url the intent was launched with
    //alert(url);
   window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(url, function(local)
    {   //deferred.resolve('file://'+local)

    alert(url);

    },function (error)
    {
        alert(error.message);
    }
    );







    alert("passing");
    //var path = converted_url.slice(0, converted_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //var filename = converted_url.substring(converted_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //alert(filepath);


}
```

});

},

Answer (score 1):

```
window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
if(url.startsWith('content://')) {

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(url, success, fail);
function success(fileEntry){
alert("present");
fileEntry.file(function(file){
    alert("is")
var ft=new FileReader();
ft.onloadend=function(e){
   // Do something
}

ft.readAsText(file);
```

});
}

if it is with "ontent://gmail-ls/myemail@gmail.com/messages/520/attachments/0.1/BEST/false" case 1 .this works